# Why the Windows 11 sees the network printer but does not connect it?

Tags: windows, networking, printing, printer, windows-11

Good morning,

I just bought a new Lenovo ideapad 3 17itl6 laptop in windows 11 version 21

it works in wifi connected to the freebox network on which is connected a pc windows 7 which manages an HP laserjet 4 printer in lpt1, yes I know that date but it works, finally it worked until today. before the lenovo, I had and still have an HP pavilion under windows 10 which prints on this Laserjet both in wifi and in ethernet so nothing to complain about on the sharing side. The HP Pavilion struggles with the fact that it only has 4G of RAM to make photo albums, so don't be in a hurry.

On the lenovo, the search for the printer "select a shared printer by name" is going well, this one is located through the network "\patrick-PC\HP laserjet 4 Plus" but during the connection phase I have a message; "Cannot connect windows to the printer. Check that the printer is powered on and that its address is correct.

what to do, I'm floundering because I tried again with the Pavilion and it works fine.

On the Lenovo, I made the Windows updates, it went to version 22. I did manual installations of the printer with the parameters copied from the pavilion, the printer seems to be created, it is well shared it is not default but the prints are queued with a printing error. Now it is not certain that my parameters point to the real printer, here I am very careful.

Why is printing done well from Windows 10 and Windows 7 on a network either wifi or ethernet!!

Win11 would be involved?

Of course it is impossible to have the micromachine support online
I posted on the answermicrosoft forum, no valid answers

Thank you for your opinions

If no solution, I will return the Lenovo to Amazon and see if I can buy an 8G laptop with Ram but under Win10.